# Error 1017 in AS3, definition of base class MovieClip not found.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
    package{//creating the basic skeleton
  imporProxy-Connection; keep-alive
Cache-Control; max-age=0

 flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
public class Turret extends MovieClip{
    private var _root:MovieClip;
```

Any ideas on whats wrong? Flash is saying that the line public class Turret extends MovieClip is the error.

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines do not seem to be AS. What's with those ?

```
 imporProxy-Connection; keep-alive
Cache-Control; max-age=0
```

also you forgot the **import** statement for MovieClip

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
```